# How Can I Make Timeouts Run in Chrome When Out of Focus?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome

I work on a mapping program that depends on AJAX calls to update the data and move markers on a (Google) map. Some of our clients use 2 monitors - they put the site on one screen in Chrome and work on the other screen. Unfortunately, Chrome seems to stop running javascript timeout() when it's OOF resulting in the map data falling way behind real-time. How can I force Chrome to pay more attention? Everything works OK in FF and IE but we want to avoid choosing a browser for people (it has led to problems before).

Comment: Can you post a link to this?  I've not seen or heard of chrome behaving this way in any other situations (I've used chrome more-or-less exclusively for a few years)

Comment: Google "Web workers" or "javascript threads"

Comment: @Neurofluxation Thanks. Will read this stuff now.

Comment: @Wug It's a well-known Chrome "feature" but I haven't found a work-around yet. Normally it seems to apply to OOF tabs, but it definitely occurs in OOF windows in our case. It's all behind passwords so I can't show you, sorry. It takes a while too.

Comment: @Pete - Created an answer for you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some Web Worker links [so you can accept my answer]

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_worker

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Using_web_workers

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/

:)